# Record dynamic PHP URL

Tags: php, google-analytics, dynamic-url

I have website visitors requesting my PHP file including variables in the URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/file.php?somevariable=blabla&othervariable=and so on
```

Is there a way to "track" or record the dynamic URL, maybe with IP adress so the output would look like this:

```
IP: 12.345.33.234 
URL:http://www.mywebsite.com/file.php?somevariable=blabla

IP: 12.345.678.234
URL:http://www.mywebsite.com/file.php?somevariable=blabla
URL:http://www.mywebsite.com/file.php?somevariable=blabla

and so on
```

I tried Google analytics but I can't make heads or tail out of it. I Googled a lot but Im not sure what Im looking for...which makes searching difficult.

Comment: Do you use apache? Just set it up to log to the access log, it will contain everything you want + more.

Comment: @JimL Yes apache, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Just enable it in your httpd.conf... more info http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog

Comment: @JimL Thank you very much, looking in to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't feel like apache's the way to go for some reason, you can create a database table to store requests in. Where you would save the IP and the current url which you can easily access with `document.URL` in javascript. Have in mind though that many computers may have the same IP within a given network, so if you'll be serving punishment for some kind of abuse, IP is not necessarily the way to go. Hope that helped, good luck! :P

Comment: I dont know anything about databases, and I would like to keep it that way for now:)

Comment: Im just looking for a simple method of having IP + dynaimc URL output, nothing fancy